# Is there a way I can set attributes on more than one element at once with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I need to do the following:

```
    $("#deleteLink").attr('data-row', $(this).attr('id'));
    $("#editLink").attr('data-row', $(this).attr('id'));
    $("#deleteLink").attr('data-href', '/Admin/Contents/Delete' + params);
    $("#editLink").attr('data-href', '/Admin/Contents/Edit' + params);
```

Is there a way I can combine the setting of these variables with jQuery.

Comment: Only the first two could be duplicated as-is. But see [`append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#deleteLink,#editLink").each(function(){
    $(this).attr('data-row', this.id);
    $(this).attr('data-href', '/Admin/Contents/'+this.id.substr(1).split("Link")[0] + params);
  });
```

OR use.data()

```
$("#deleteLink,#editLink").each(function(){
    $(this).data('row',this.id);
    $(this).data('href', '/Admin/Contents/'+this.id.substr(1).split("Link")[0] + params);
  });
```

Comment: Use `.data()` instead of `.attr('data-`.

Comment: I heard something about .data converting strings to numbers. My strings are "000300". I had to use attr when reading the values. Is there an advantage when it comes to setting the data- ?  Thanks

Comment: I just tested it and that didn't happen to me.

Comment: @Blender - `.data()` doesn't set attributes. It stores arbitrary data that is associated with the DOM element, but not as an attribute, and when said value is retrieved no data conversion applies. It can _retrieve_ `.data-` attributes, and when it does _that_ it tries to do data conversion. In my opinion including this duel functionality in `.data()` was a bad call.

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't make it clear what `this` is where you've used `$(this).attr("id")`. If it is some *other* element, because, e.g., the four lines you've shown are inside some other element's click handler or something, then in my opinion the most efficient and easy to read way to do it is like this:

```
$("#deleteLink").attr({'data-row' : this.id,
                       'data-href' : '/Admin/Contents/Delete' + params});
$("#editLink").attr({'data-row' : this.id,
                     'data-href' : '/Admin/Contents/Edit' + params});
```

That is, use the syntax of `.attr()` that lets you pass in a map to set multiple attribute values on the same element at once, but do the link elements one at a time since they will have different `data-href` values set.

However, that doesn't actually answer your question about setting more than one element's attributes at once, which you can do like this:

```
$("#deleteLink,#editLink").attr('data-row', this.id)
                          .attr('data-href', function(i,a) {
                              var action = this.id.split("Link")[0];
                              return '/Admin/Contents/' +
                                     action.charAt(0).toUpperCase() +
                                     action.substr(1) + params;
                           });
```

The first line of that creates a jQuery object containing both link elements, and uses `.attr('data-row', this.id)` to set them both to have the same `data-row` attribute equal to whatever value `this.id` holds. (I'm still assuming `this` is some other element.)

The second line *chains* another call to `.attr()` (to avoid having to call the `$()` function again to select the same elements again), this time using the syntax of `.attr()` where you pass a callback function - this function is called for each element being processed where within the function `this` is the element being modified and the attribute is set to whatever you return.

[More info about the `.attr()` method here.](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)